# Combine Pages module and the default URL behavior

Tags: pages

An existing site uses the Pages module. There are already way too much pages and I have to add new pages now with content from a new channel.

Can I use for the new page/s the EE templategroup/template URLs and not using the Pages module?

Can both ways, Pages and the default URL behavior, be combined in one install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that will work. I do it all the time.